# RollingAppender doesn't delete old logs (log4j2)

Tags: java, log4j2

Here is my log4j2.yaml.
Now this logger create 1 file in day and when this day will end - the logger will create a folder "archive" and will put old log file to this folder.
I need to delete all the old logs which are have been created 7 days ago.
What did I do wrong? Help me, please

```
Configuration:


status: debug

  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: LogToConsole
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"

RollingFile:
  - name: LogToRollingFile
    fileName: logs/hippodrome.log
    filePattern: "logs/archive/hippodrome.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"
    PatternLayout:
      pattern: "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"
    Policies:
      TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
        interval: 1
      SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
        size: = 1 KB
    DefaultRolloverStrategy:
      Delete:
        basePath: logs/
        maxDepth: 3
        IfFileName:
          glob: "hippodrome.*.log"
        IfLastModified:
          age: P7D

  Loggers:
    logger:
      - name: org.example
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: LogToRollingFile

Root:
  level: error
  AppenderRef:
    - ref: LogToConsole
  AppenderRef:
    - ref: LogToRollingFile
```

Answer (score 1):

I think cronTrigger policy could be used as per the documentation [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover). Also looks like indentation is missing for RollingFile appender which should be parallel to Console appender. Made few changes to your log4j2.yml file below.

```
Configuration:
  status: debug
  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: LogToConsole
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  RollingFile:
    - name: LogToRollingFile
      fileName: logs/hippodrome.log
      filePattern: "logs/archive/hippodrome.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"
      Policies:
        TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          interval: 1
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
          size: 1 KB

      DefaultRolloverStrategy:
        Delete:
          basePath: logs/
          maxDepth: 2
          IfFileName:
            glob: "*/hippodrome.*.log"
          IfLastModified:
            age: P7D

  Loggers:
    Logger:
      - name: org.example
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: LogToRollingFile

    Root:
      level: error
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: LogToConsole
      AppenderRef:
        - ref: LogToRollingFile
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very sad, but nothing has been changed with adding CronTriggerPolicy :( And In my file, I have an indentation for RollingFile ... Idk why it happened here :)

Comment: What is the current situation? Is this configuration partially working or not working at all? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Now this properties doing like this : 1) create a .log file in logs/ . 2) at midnight he put old log file to “logs/archive/” folder. Everything logging good like I need . But I need one more thing . That this old logs which are in logs/archive/  must be deleted if .log was created 7 days ago and older. In documentation for log4j2 says , that I need to use DefaultRolloverStrategy for this . But something in this block I did wrong . That’s why I need your help :)

Comment: @DenysDudnik, I made few changes in DefaultRolloverStrategy (i.e maxDepth and glob) and did some formatting.  Can you please take the entire log4j2 yml configurations above and give it try.